# Как внести имя шаблона в класс с помощью using declaration?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

```
template<typename T>
struct Base {
    using type_from_base = T;

    template<typename T2>
    struct template_from_base {};
};

template<typename T>
class Derived : Base<T> {
public:
//    using Base<T>::type_from_base; // error
    using typename Base<T>::type_from_base;

//    using Base<T>::template template_from_base; // error
    // ???

    type_from_base        member_1;
    template_from_base<T> member_2;
};


int main() {
    Derived<int> x{};
}
```

Чтобы внести имя зависимого типа из базового класса в класс-наследник с помощью `using declaration`, нужно явно указать ключевое слово `typename`. Но как внести имя шаблона в таком случае? Интересует решение как для шаблонного класса, так и для шаблонной функции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Алиас для шаблона будет

```
template<typename T2> using
template_from_base = typename Base<T>::template template_from_base<T2>;
```

Для шаблонной функции ничего необычного, `using Base<T>::foo;`

Comment: А как вы указываете аргумент шаблона для шаблонной функции?

Comment: @cppquestions Никак

Comment: Как её вызвать из класса `Derived` тогда?

Comment: @cppquestions Вот как раз при вызове надо будет указать параметр шаблона. А при внесении имени - не надо

Comment: Я это и имел в виду. Не могли бы вы привести пример такого вызова? Или любой инстанции такой функции

Comment: @cppquestions Вызов обычный,  `x.foo<int>();` например